# How to replace NPM node_module folder with another folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

By default of NPM is installing the modules under "node_modules".
Is there a way to change it to be for example "my_modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard for all node modules is to use the `node_modules` directory.

Do not try to go against this uniform standard.

What are you trying to accomplish by customizing the directory?

---

Note:

The following command will install a module to `my_project/node_modules/some_module`

```
[~/my_project] $ npm install some_module
```

If you'd like to install modules and have them globally available on your system, you can use the `--global` (`-g`) flag

```
[~/my_project] $ npm install -g some_module
```

Packages installed with the `-g` flag are installed to `~/.npm`

---

### EDIT

Per your comment, you can attempt to install any directory that contains a `package.json` file

```
[~/my_project] $ npm install /path/to/my/pkg
```

Alternatively you can install a symbolic link instead of copying the entire module to your `~/my_project/node_modules` directory.

```
[~/my_project] $ npm link /path/to/my/pkg
```

For more info about this:

```
$ npm help install
$ npm help link
```

Comment: I want to use npm to install not only my node packages, but also other packages I use.

Comment: Specific situation:
I'd like to run a node app using vagrant.  When the host OS is windows, and the client is Linux, you're unable to run applications from /vagrant because of wonky permissions.  This doesn't affect the node application directly, but it does affect node modules that ship with executables.

Comment: @DustyJ I have no experience using Vagrant or node.js on Windows. I cannot provide any help for such a configuration.

Comment: Was surprised that we would advise people to not customize a folder location. That seems pretty rigid. If I have a portion of the project that uses node and I wish to keep it within that scope instead of polluting the root dir, there has to be a way. 

I thought this was easily doable with a file like `.npmrc` and have been looking for answers. No luck yet. 

Edit: Added the line about .npmrc

Comment: If you think adding a `node_modules` folder to the root directory of your project that uses node, you're going to find that every module (with a dependency) has a "polluted" root directory. There's a standard for a reason. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @VinayRaghu, anyway, what's stopping you from putting all of the node components of your app in a subdirectory? If you do `mkdir foo; cd foo; npm init; npm install whatever`, your node app will be in `foo` and your node modules will be installed to `foo/node_modules`. This follows npm standards and organizes your node app nicely.

Comment: @maček You're right. There's a standard for a reason. I was surprised because this was new to me. Regarding the sub folder, that's how it currently is being maintained. Thank you