# How to set custom location for local installation of npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to specify a custom package destination for `npm install`, either through a command flag or environment variable?

By default, npm local installs end up in `node_modules` within the current directory, but I want it to install into `node_modules` within a different directory, for example `vendor/node_modules`. How can I make that happen?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  this has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668097/how-to-replace-npm-node-module-folder-with-another-folder

Comment: @PascalBelloncle: Instead of installing packages into subdirectories of `./node_modules`, I want npm to install them into subdirectories of  `./vendor/node_modules`. (Or to be told that that isn't configurable.)

Comment: I understood that's what you want to do, which I don't think is possible out of the box.  Plus require would not work either.  So I was asking why you wanted to do this.  Maybe there is an alternative solution to do what you want.

Comment: I'm installing a package solely for its binary (i.e. it will only be used on the command line and never `require`d) but I don't want to install it globally.

Comment: I see.  See my suggestion below then.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can do this by using the `--prefix` flag and the `--global`* flag.

```
pje@friendbear:~/foo $ npm install bower -g --prefix ./vendor/node_modules
bower@0.7.0 /Users/pje/foo/vendor/node_modules/bower
```

*Even though this is a "global" installation, installed bins won't be accessible through the command line unless `~/foo/vendor/node_modules` exists in `PATH`.

#### TL;DR

Every configurable attribute of `npm` can be set in any of six different places. In order of priority:

- Command-Line Flags:    `--prefix ./vendor/node_modules`
- Environment Variables: `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=./vendor/node_modules`
- User Config File:      `$HOME/.npmrc` or `userconfig` param
- Global Config File:    `$PREFIX/etc/npmrc` or `userconfig` param
- Built-In Config File:  `path/to/npm/itself/npmrc`
- Default Config:        [node_modules/npmconf/config-defs.js](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/node_modules/npmconf/config-defs.js)

By default, locally-installed packages go into `./node_modules`. global ones go into the `prefix` config variable (`/usr/local` by default).

You can run `npm config list` to see your current config and `npm config edit` to change it.

#### PS

In general, `npm`'s documentation is really helpful. The [folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) section is a good structural overview of npm and the [config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) section answers this question.

Comment: As I test, actually if follow the command above, it will be installed into 
`./vendor/node_modules/lib/bower` using `npm#3.8.0`

Comment: When doing this, I am getting error `No version provided in package.json`

Comment: You write `bins won't be accessible through the command line`. The program can of course be invoked using the complete path `npm install eslint@3.4.0 -g --prefix c:\my_npm\` calling `c:\my_npm\eslint --fix my.js`

Comment: Is it possible to achieve something similar with a package.json file? i.e. if I run `npm install` in directory A with package.json file, packages will be install in directory B. It seems this solution is for individual packages being installed.

Comment: Is there any way of installing all dependencies using this method? `npm install` installs dependencies locally. `npm install X -g -prefix "..."` installs module X to the prefix, `npm install -g -prefix "..."` installs the current package to the prefix.

Comment: So my understanding from this answer is, I cannot stop npm littering my user `%userprofile%` , %appdata%, environment variables, etc.? How do I tell npm that it is not allowed to bring his toys to living room, kitchen and hallway and generally all over place or in other words it only can keep his toys in his own room at `D:\Projects\`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: instead of installing deps to the prefix, it creates a symlink under the prefix leading back to the current directory, and claims that it installed "1 package". Repeating the command gives "up to date", [which is probably related to this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44493260/2388257#npm-install-showing-up-to-date-instead-of-installing-the-packages).

Answer (score 37):

If you want this in config, you can set npm config like so:

```
npm config set prefix "$(pwd)/vendor/node_modules"
```

or

```
npm config set prefix "$HOME/vendor/node_modules"
```

Check your config with

`npm config ls -l`

Or as @pje says and use the `--prefix` flag

Comment: I believe this sets the global prefix? So doing `npm install` will still install locally to `./node_modules` but `npm install -g` will install to `"$(pwd)/vendor/node_modules"`. I can imagine settings this then forgetting about it, coming back later wondering why my global packages are acting weirdly.

Answer (score 16):

For OSX, you can go to your user's `$HOME` (probably /Users/yourname/) and, if it doesn't already exist, create an `.npmrc` file (a file that npm uses for user configuration), and create a directory for your npm packages to be installed in (e.g., /Users/yourname/npm). In that .npmrc file, set "prefix" to your new npm directory, which will be where "globally" installed npm packages will be installed; these "global" packages will, obviously, be available only to your user account.

In .npmrc:

`prefix=${HOME}/npm`

Then run this command from the command line:

`npm config ls -l`

It should give output on both your own local configuration and the global npm configuration, and you should see your local prefix configuration reflected, probably near the top of the long list of output.

For security, I recommend this approach to configuring your user account's npm behavior over chown-ing your `/usr/local` folders, which I've seen recommended elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows 7 for example, the following set of commands/operations could be used.

Create an personal environment variable, double backslashes are mandatory:

- Variable name: `%NPM_HOME%`
- Variable value: `C:\\SomeFolder\\SubFolder\\`

Now, set the config values to the new folders (examplary file names):

- Set the npm folder

`npm config set prefix "%NPM_HOME%\\npm"`

- Set the npm-cache folder

`npm config set cache "%NPM_HOME%\\npm-cache"`

- Set the npm temporary folder

`npm config set tmp "%NPM_HOME%\\temp"`

Optionally, you can purge the contents of the original folders **before** the config is changed.

- Delete the npm-cache    `npm cache clear`
- List the npm modules    `npm -g ls`
- Delete the npm modules
  `npm -g rm name_of_package1 name_of_package2`

Comment: Thanks, I follow the steps. But it creates a directory called c:/%NPM_HOME%/npm, etc. instead of c:/npm_home/npm

Answer (score 7):

After searching for this myself wanting several projects with shared dependencies to be DRYer, I’ve found:

- Installing locally is the Node way for anything you want to use via `require()`
- Installing globally is for binaries you want in your path, but is not intended for anything via `require()`
- Using a prefix means you need to add appropriate `bin` and `man` paths to `$PATH`
- `npm link` ([info](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html)) lets you use a local install as a source for globals

→ stick to the Node way and install locally

*ref:*

- [Perfect summary from isaacs](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/775#issuecomment-1389398)
- npm FAQ: ["node_modules" is the name of my deity's arch-rival, and a Forbidden Word in my religion. Can I configure npm to use a different folder?](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#node_modules-is-the-name-of-my-deity-s-arch-rival-and-a-Forbidden-Word-in-my-religion-Can-I-configure-npm-to-use-a-different-folder) ;-)

Comment: This should be a comment as it adds nothing on the point. It basically summarizes to "install packages locally", which is exactly what the OP does, and OP is asking how to make local installation use a different directory. This answer also mentions "when to use global installation", but does not mention how's that relevant to the question. Idk how this  unrelated text got 8 points ‍♂️

Comment: Btw, every link in the answer is 404. Mentioning in case they contained something important.