# How to change package.json output location

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, node-modules

Is there a package.json option to specify the relative location of the node_modules directory?

For my application I have a directory structure that looks like the following.

#### Current Directory Structure

```
root/
---/client
-------/(client code)
---/server
------/package.json* (sibling of node_modules)
------/node_modules*
------/server.js
```

I'd like to add [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) tasks to the project's root directory (since they'll apply to both the client code and server code). Gruntfile.js needs to be a [sibling of package.json](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#the-gruntfile).

I'd like to move package.json to the root directory for this reason, but I'd also like to keep the node_modules within the server directory. Is there an option within package.json to do this?

I'd like the resulting directory structure to look like the following.

#### Preferred Directory Structure

```
root/
---/package.json* (not a sibling of node_modules)
---/Gruntfile.js
---/client
-------/(client code)
---/server
------/node_modules*
```

An option like the following would be the most preferred (there does not seem to be an option like this in the [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html))

#### Hypothetical package.json

```
{
   "output_dir": "server/node_modules", // Something like this
   "dependencies": { ... },
   "devDependencies": { ... }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [npm local install package to custom location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for that as I want to use the same structure for my heroku app. Heroku force you to have the package.json in the root...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the prefix option on CLI.

```
npm install express --prefix ./server/node_modules
```

Don't know similar option exists via package.json

Comment: Hmm, this still requires that my package.json be in the same directory as node_modules. Otherwise I get the error: `"npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies"`