# jpm-mobile fails with ReferenceError: cmd is not defined

Tags: android, node.js, npm, firefox-addon

Here is the stacktrace shown:

```
$ /tmp/node_modules/jpm-mobile/bin/jpm-mobile init
/tmp/node_modules/jpm-mobile/bin/jpm-mobile:50
if (cmd.isEmptyCommand(program)) {
    ^
ReferenceError: cmd is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node_modules/jpm-mobile/bin/jpm-mobile:50:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

`npm list` shows jpm-mobile installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `jpm-mobile`, solution can be found in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/ncalexan/jpm-mobile/commit/5f4455c072dcffad6c079ff6696164300ba76774).