# npm --save-dev not working with --prefix

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run this:

```
npm install angular-mocks --save-dev
```

I get angular-mocks in ./node_modules and a reference to angular mocks in ./package.json

When I run this:

```
npm install angular-mocks --prefix ./Content/libs
```

I get angular-mocks in ./Content/libs/node_modules

When I run this:

```
npm install angular-mocks --save-dev --prefix ./Content/libs
```

I get angular-mocks in ./Content/libs/nod_modules but no reference to anguar-mocks in ./package.json

Why is npm not saving the reference in package.json when I use --prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is npm not saving the reference in `package.json` when I use `--prefix`?

It is (or at least will do), but it is expecting `package.json` to be in the parent folder of wherever it drops the `node_modules` folder.

In your case this would be `./Content/libs`.

Try it out:

```
mkdir -p ~/test/Content/libs
cd ~/test/Content/libs
npm init (accept defaults)
cd ~/test
npm install angular-mocks --save-dev --prefix ./Content/libs
cat ~/test/Content/libs/package.json
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "libs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.8"
  }
}
```

As you can see, angular-mocks has been saved to the devDependencies.

This SO thread contains a little more detail on installing local packages to a custom location: [npm local install package to custom location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location)

Comment: Which version of npm are you using?