# Installing node modules of Angular 2 app in a common folder

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-install

I have multiple Angular 2 projects and each of them contains `package.json` file. I run `npm install` command on those files to install node modules for each of those project. Since each project has a `node_modules` folder now, I'd like to have just one `node_modules` folder shared among all projects and install additional modules to that folder.

I tried running `npm install --prefix ..` command in first project. Here's the result:

```
-my_projects
--project1
---package.json
--project2
---package.json
--project3
---package.json
--node_modules
---project1
----node_modules
----all_other_project_files_and_folders
--etc
```

What happened? Yes, `node_modules` folder in a parent folder was created as I expected, but in that folder, a copy of my entire project is also included. I just wanted to install all of my project's dependencies in one common folder instead of duplicating those modules' installations in multiple projects.

How can I achieve this? Is a '--prefix' option the right way at all?

Answer (score 0):

This similar question might help you out: [npm local install package to custom location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location)

Although I would suggest just installing globally using the `-g` or `--global` flags if your goal is to have npm packages available to all (current and future) projects.

Example: `sudo npm install express -g`