# How to change bower's installation folder?

Tags: bower-install

When I try to install bower in my working project folder using `npm install -g bower` command in Windows 7 it is installed in another folder. I delete that folder and try to reinstall it. But again automatically that folder is created and bower is installed within that folder. See the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4fUX.png). I want to install bower in the otenro folder. But each and every time it is installed in angular folder. How do I change that?

Comment: please can someone help me for this I'm new for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your default install location:

```
npm list -g
```

To change your default install location:

```
npm config set prefix "C:\My\New\Location"
```

So after changing the install location just install bower and it will be installed there. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location) can help in any further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new file in the root of the project. The file has no name, only with the extension:

**.bowerrc**

with this:

```
{
  "directory": "Mynewdirectory/newfolder/subfolder"
}
```

Comment: @kalani you should mark the right answer to help others.

Comment: In my case I solved my problem by using [ npm config set prefix "C:\My\New\Location" ]. It works for me. I already included .bowerrc file with 
{
  "directory": "Mynewdirectory/newfolder/subfolder"
}
but It didn't work.

Comment: Then mark the @PiotrWolkowski answer as the right. This is how the site works.