# Change node modules packages path in symfony3

Tags: symfony, node-modules

I am installing bootstrap and jquery with npm. I want only ( not the sass files ) the jquery and bootstrap files to be installed in `web/vendor` and not in `node_submodules/..`. Is that possible?

So my symfony structure looks like this

```
app
bin
composer.json
composer.lock
Gruntfile.js
node_modules
- bootstrap and jquery files are here <<
package.json
src
tests
var
vendor
web
- vendor
  - I want my bootstrap and jquery files here <<
```

Or should I just download bootstrap and jquery and place them myself in `web/vendor` and forget about node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

See [npm local install package to custom location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location).

Using your approach is fine for a small project, but if you plan on building a more ambitious application, you should really look into using a build tool like webpack, gulp, or grunt. Then you can package up your javascript dependencies from your node_modules into a single file and have it generated into your public js folder.