# Change the location of the nodemodules folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

Consider my project structure is like:

```
stackoverflow/
              src/
                  java/
                       src/

                  js/
                    node_modules/
                    package.json
                    src/

              build/
                  stackoverflow.war
```

when I run "npm run install" from stackoverflow/src/js, node_modules directory gets placed inside js folder. Is it possible to configure "npm run install" to generate node_modules inside stackoverflow/build/?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm local install package to custom location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location)

Comment: My qn is specific to side effects on react application

Comment: It doesn't belong in either of those places--it's neither built (rather used to build) nor your source.