# Correct way to deal with downloaded d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped when installed via npm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript, npm, tfs

- Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise
- ASP.NET MVC Application
- TypeScript 2.5 SDK
- Source control is in TFS

I am using Microsofts built in property editor instead of a custom tsconfig.config file:

[image]

To allow an easy workflow I am using Mad's Kristensen's [Package Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.PackageInstaller) to do my NPM installations of [Definitively Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) TypeScript definitions within my MVC web project.

Ultimately this ends up creating **node_modules** in a folder under the solution path:

[image]

While I could use this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867050/223742) post to do a GLOBAL install using **-g --prefix** so that I could place this into a folder of my choosing say:

***MVCProjectFolder*\TypeScript\Npm\Modules**

I have some concerns or at least a request for a better way.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a different way to changing the node_modules folder from within Visual Studio without specifying -g -prefix
2. What is the best approach to bundle all the TS generated JavaScript in the project? (The TypeScript Build property option "Compile JavaScript output into file" appears to have no effect)

[image]

3. Do I only need to include the d.ts tiles in TFS so that the following will keep on working when synced?

--

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "include the d.ts tiles in TFS"?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I mean check them into version control.

Answer (score 0):

Answer your TFS part, you don't need to check in node_modules folder to TFS. When you want to build your project in TFS, add a nmp task in your build definition:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/npm

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here? I am talking specifically about the d.ts files themselves

Comment: I mean the d.ts files in node_modules folder like `/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts` doesn't need to check into TFS.