# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve vue, path not correct

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have my webpack.config.js and node_modules in a subfolder. If I trying to execute: `npm run build` I get the error: `ERROR in ../public/Vue/Components/Rating.vue Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue'`. I think the path is incorrect, but i trying last 3 hours and i didn't find a solution.

the folder structure looks like:

```
project/
 +public/
    Vue/
      Components/
         Rating.vue
      main.js
    Dist/
 +webpack/
   webpack.config.js
   package.json
   node_modules/
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var target = '../public/Vue/main.js';

var output = {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/Dist/'),
    filename: 'default.js'
}


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: target,
  output: {
    path: output.path,
    filename: output.filename
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  },

module: {
    rules: [
      ... // load loader
    ]
  },
 ....
}
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Rating from "./Components/Rating.vue";

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      content: "Hello World",
    }
  },

  components: {
    Rating,
  }
});
```

I hope somebody can me help out :)

**Error message**

```
ERROR in ../public/Vue/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\Vue'
 @ ../public/Vue/main.js 1:0-22


ERROR in ../public/Vue/Components/Rating.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-style-loader' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\Vue\Components'
 @ ../public/Vue/Components/Rating.vue 2:2-297
 @ ../public/Vue/main.js
```

Comment: `node_modules` should be at the root of the project.

Comment: Or make sure there's a [configuration that tells npm where to install modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14742553/1218980)

Answer (score 29):

This question ranks high in google, so I would add a settings for Vue 3. With Webpack 5 and Vue 3, the webpack *config* alias changes to this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue' ],
    alias: {
        'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom'
    }
},
```

Alternatively this may be the solution, if the are transpilation errors:

```
    alias: {
        'Vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
    }
```

Hope it saves time for others.

Answer (score 3):

looks like something you might get when you don't run `npm install`

can you check that the `vue` folder exists in `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\Vue\node_modules` ?

Comment: I did have my node_modules folder with its tons of files, but nonetheless got the error in the OP.

Following your advice, I ran `npm install` again, and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be the case when you migrate from vue2 to vue3 and forget to remove the alias when finished and removing @vue/compat helper migration build

```
chainWebpack(config) {
// helper to upgrade vue2 to vue3
config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat');
```