# is it possible to let different entry package to different output path in webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack to package a google chrome extension, I want to keep the folder structure in the dist folder. for example, I want to package all popup resource in the `dist/popup/*`, this is my config right now:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    popup : './src/popup/' 
  } ,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805384/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-vue-path-not-correct
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    },
  },
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../../bundle') ,
    filename : '[path]/[name].js'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/ ,
        exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      } ,
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins : [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src/manifest.json", to: "manifest.json" },
        { from: "src/resource/image", to: "resource/image" },
      ],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'popup.html',
      template: 'src/popup/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
    }),
  ]
};
```

I have tried to tweak the output filename like this:

```
filename : '[path]/[name].js'
```

seems did not work. I am searching from google and did not found any suggestion. Is it possible to do like this? or different entry with different dist folder.

Comment: check this. i hope this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426778/6018827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am define the entry like this:

```
entry : {
    'popup/popup' : './src/popup/' 
  } ,
```

this would generate a popup folder in the dist.