# Error: TypeScript emitted no output for when added id for div in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs3

When I add the id for template in vue 3 like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="11">I am a translator</div>
</template>
```

the typescript compile has an error:

```
WARNING in ./src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue 8:68-74
export 'render' (imported as 'render') was not found in './Translator.vue?vue&type=template&id=08844f3e&scoped=true&ts=true' (module has no exports)
 @ ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[8].use[0]!./src/popup/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 3:0-68 12:22-32
 @ ./src/popup/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 1:0-189 1:0-189 1:190-368 1:190-368
 @ ./src/popup/App.vue 2:0-54 3:0-49 3:0-49 6:49-55
 @ ./src/popup/index.ts 2:0-28 4:14-17

ERROR in ./src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue?vue&type=template&id=08844f3e&scoped=true&ts=true (./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[8].use[0]!./src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue?vue&type=template&id=08844f3e&scoped=true&ts=true)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue.ts.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
    at successLoader (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
    at Object.loader (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)
 @ ./src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue?vue&type=template&id=08844f3e&scoped=true&ts=true 1:0-303 1:0-303
 @ ./src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue 1:0-91 8:68-74
 @ ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[8].use[0]!./src/popup/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 3:0-68 12:22-32
 @ ./src/popup/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 1:0-189 1:0-189 1:190-368 1:190-368
 @ ./src/popup/App.vue 2:0-54 3:0-49 3:0-49 6:49-55
 @ ./src/popup/index.ts 2:0-28 4:14-17

webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 69 ms
```

I check my `tsconfig.json` and make sure that `noEmit` was set to false. why would this happen? what should I do to fix this? this is the whole vue component code:

```
<template>
    <div id ="11">I am a translator</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const title = process.env.APP_NAME
    return {
      title
    }
  },
  components: {
    //Options,
  },
  render(){
    return "ddddd";
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
div.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  hr {
    size: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    color: gray;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
</style>
```

and this is the webpack config:

```
 const path = require('path');
  const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin');
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin');
  const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
  const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

  module.exports = {
    entry : {
      'popup/popup' : './src/popup/' 
    } ,
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805384/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-vue-path-not-correct
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018431/webpack-5-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined
          process: 'process/browser',
          //'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
    output : {
      path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../../bundle') ,
      filename : '[name].js'
    },
    module : {
      rules : [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: 'vue-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
          },
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        
        {
          test : /\.js$/ ,
          exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
          loader : 'babel-loader'
        } ,
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins : [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: "src/manifest.json", to: "manifest.json" },
          { from: "src/resource/image", to: "resource/image" },
        ],
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'popup/popup.html',
        template: 'src/popup/index.html'
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
        __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
      }),
    ]
  };
```

**Tried 1:** I tried to ignore the `.d.ts` file like this:

```
{
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
          },
          exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/
        },
        {
          test: /\.d\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ignore-loader'
        },
```

seems did not work.

Comment: Did you ever fixed this? Running into the exact same issue here.

Comment: No, I did not fixed this problem. @FerryKranenburg I was rewrite the project using vue3 without upgrade it.