# How to build a multi package node module with some optional modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, lerna

I am trying since several days to build a node module which will be used by a react application.

Today my module is packaged as a big javascript file packaged with **webpack**.
Some part of this node module is optional and is only needed if we want to use certain features (activated through config). In order to avoid loading unecessary part of the code, I have tried first to use *chunking* and *dynamic import* as explained by **webpack** but this has not worked: chunks are created and packaged in the `dist/` folder but i never succeed to run the dynamic import in the node module when called from the react app. The application complains that the chunk cannot be loaded from the app. This make sense for me as this webpack feature was more built to load dynamically part of the application and not as an internal mechanism for a node module dependency to load code on demand (but i could be wrong).

I looked at other projects like *babel* or *react-router* where the module is split in several package using **lerna** and **yarn package**. So i have tried to build the library with **lerna** with different packages:

```
my-library
  core/
    src/
      index.js
  another-package/
    src/
      index.js
```

I want the `index.js` file from `core` to call a method from `index.js`from `another-package` only if needed and only if the node-module `@my-library/another-package` was installed. But i never found the solution to do it.
Is it possible to achieve this with `ES5`/`ES6` with `webpack`/`lerna` or did i took the wrong approach?

**UPDATE October 27TH**

So after several tests, I was able to use Aram solution with a plain HTML/JS (https://github.com/PixelDuck/lerna-webpack/blob/main/a-react-app/src/client/test.html) but the solution is not working with a react app package with webpack https://github.com/PixelDuck/lerna-webpack/blob/main/a-react-app/src/client/App.js.

The code is available there: https://github.com/PixelDuck/lerna-webpack.

Open a terminal to `my-lerna-library` and run
`yarn install`
`yarn link:all`, this will create symbolic link for each packages
`yarn dev', this will create bundle and listen to changes

then open a new terminal to folder `a-react-app`:
`yarn install`
`yarn link "my-lerna-library"`
`yarn link "@my-lerna-library/another-package"`
`yarn dev``

a page will be open on `http://0.0.0.0:3000` and you will see that module `@my-lerna-library/another-package` is not found.

If you open `http://0.0.0.0:5000/test.html` the plainJS test, everything is looking fine.

It seems that the issue is on the webpack side for the react app because when debugging the application i can see that the core package is looking to a library name `my_lerna_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__` which is not the one used by webpack when loading the other package `_my_lerna_library_another_package__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default`

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js");
/* harmony import */ var _App_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./App.css */ "./src/client/App.css");
/* harmony import */ var _App_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_App_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
/* harmony import */ var _my_lerna_library_another_package__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @my-lerna-library/another-package */ "../my-lerna-library/packages/another-package/dist/index.bundle.js");
/* harmony import */ var _my_lerna_library_another_package__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_my_lerna_library_another_package__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__);
/* harmony import */ var my_lerna_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! my-lerna-library */ "../my-lerna-library/packages/core/dist/index.bundle.js");
/* harmony import */ var my_lerna_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(my_lerna_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to achieve what i want.
Code here: https://github.com/PixelDuck/lerna-webpack

So the idea was to set another-package webpack config to output library as 'global' and on core package, looking at this global variable with

```
function isMyLernaLibraryAnotherPackageDefined() {
  return typeof myLernaLibraryAnotherPackage !== 'undefined';
}
```

```
testFromAnotherPackage() {
  if (isMyLernaLibraryAnotherPackageDefined())
    return new myLernaLibraryAnotherPackage.AnotherClass().test();
}
```

Now on the react app, if i am importing `import '@my-lerna-library/another-package';`then message and svg are displayed.
If i am commenting this line, module is not found and nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

In your my-lerna-library > package:-

(1) another-package package.json file replace with this code

```
{
  "name": "@my-lerna-library/another-package",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --devtool inline-source-map --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-lerna-library/core": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

and

(2) core package.json file replace with this code

```
{
  "name": "@my-lerna-library/core",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --devtool inline-source-map --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

and my-lerna-library package.json file replace workspaces like this,

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/**"
    ]
},
```

Then run command "yarn run dev". I thing this is work for you!!

Comment: Hi. thanks for your time. I have tried and it's not working.
In the code generated for core i can see
```
      anotherPackage = __webpack_require__(Object(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module '@my-lerna-library/another-package'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
```
So this will not work. Defining in core another-package as optionalPeerDependencies and declared as external in webpack config fix the code:
```
      anotherPackage = __webpack_require__(/*! @my-lerna-library/another-package */ "@my-lerna-library/another-package");```

Comment: And issue is still there on web app:
 WARNING in ../my-lerna-library/packages/core/dist/index.bundle.js 6:13-57
[1] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@my-lerna-library/another-package' in '/Users/olmartin/dev/js/lerna-webpack/my-lerna-library/packages/core/dist'

Check branch https://github.com/PixelDuck/lerna-webpack/tree/deep_comment

I think the issue is not on the library side but on the webapp side where i am not able to import the dependency in the scope and make the core library view it with require().

Answer (score -1):

If you need a package with optional dependencies you can create a *core package* together with several *feature packages* (which are ***not*** even listed in peerDependencies). You may explicitly list those feature packages in `optionalDependencies`.

Also, you core package should be designed so that it does not necessary require feature packages but can correctly work with them if they're installed. For example this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841764/14451484.

Comment: Hello Your solution sounds promising but i was not able to make it works. 
after your changes, the method from core library always returns this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@my-lerna-library/another-package'
    at webpackEmptyContext 
    at loadOptionalPackage
    at Object../src/index.js 
    at __nested_webpack_require_5300__
    at index.bundle.js:19
    at index.bundle.js:192
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition
    at Object../node_modules/my-lerna-library/dist/index.bundle.js
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)   
```

Comment: Notice that optionalDependencies make webpack dev stuck on core package so i had to use `optionalPeerDependencies`.

Comment: I have updated my issue with some news and a test case on github if you have time to have a look.....