# Unable to install botskills command

Tags: azure, azure-devops, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

**Unable to install npm botskills command on Self-Hosted Azure agent.**

Used following command to install packages get updated but when tried to check using "botskills" command it throws up and error saying botskills not available.

Screenshots

Used " npm install -g botskills@latest " to install the package where the following screenshot infers that the botskill packages have been updated.

[image]

But when tried to use the updated package it does not work

[image]

All the other supporting packages have been updated.

This issue occurs while using the Self-Hosted agent (Windows agent) only and works with no issue on local.

**Steps to reproduce**
1) Use any of the Microsoft Self-Hosted Agent.
2) Try installing botkskills using following command *npm install -g botskills@latest*
  (Follow the attached screenshots)
3) Try using botskills to verify if the package is available.

Comment: Hi @Priyanka Shetty Did you checkout below answer, and add the botskills package installation path to Environment PATH? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is supported on a Azure agent, but this looks like a pathing issue.

On a typical machine, in powershell you can run the following to check what your path variable is set to:

`$env:path.split(";")`

You should typically have something like:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` as one of the paths.

For me, bot skills is at:
`C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\npm\botskills.ps1`

If you don't have that npm path in your path variable, that needs to be remedied somehow. If it's there, then you need to verify that botskills.ps1 is there.

When everything *is* setup correctly, you can use the following in PowerShell to find the path:

`get-command botskills | select path`

Answer (score 0):

The error botskills not recognized is because the botskills package installation path is not in the System Environment variables PATH of you local machine. Azure pipeline agent is running as a different user (by default the NetworkService user), and the botskills package is installed by azure pipeline in a different path that unknown to system environment path.

You need to manually add the "path" to the system environment Path for the self-hosted agent machine.

You can also use `--prefix` to specify a custom npm package installation folder, and make sure add the path to system environment path for the self-hosted agent machine.

`npm install botskills@latest -g --prefix C:\custompath\npm`

Or you can add the installation path to Environment path in the powershell task using below script.

`$env:Path += ";C:\path to botskills installation\npm"`

Please check the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/how-to-set-custom-location-for-local-installation-of-npm-package) for more information and the discussion for a similar issue [here](https://github.com/carlowahlstedt/NewmanPostman_VSTS_Task/issues/37).